JupyterHub Docker setup: Unable to login with admin credentials, encountering configuration warnings
I'm setting up JupyterHub using Docker and encountering issues with user authentication and configuration warnings. Here's my setup:
# Dockerfile
# Use Python 3.11 base image
FROM python:3.11-bookworm

# Set environment variables
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 \
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    PYTHONFAULTHANDLER=1 \
    PYTHONHASHSEED=random \
    PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on \
    PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE=false \
    POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1 \
    POETRY_VERSION=1.8.3 \
    PATH="/root/.local/bin:$PATH" \
    NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/node_modules

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install necessary packages including pycurl dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    curl \
    openssl \
    gnupg \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && npm install -g npm@latest \
    && npm install -g configurable-http-proxy \
    && curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 - \
    && poetry --version

# Adjust permissions for Poetry
RUN chmod +x /root/.local/bin/poetry

# Copy project dependencies and install
COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./
RUN poetry install --no-root

# Create necessary directories and generate SSL certificates
RUN mkdir -p /srv/jupyterhub/ssl_cert /var/log/jupyterhub && \
    openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 \
    -keyout /srv/jupyterhub/ssl_cert/localhost.key \
    -out /srv/jupyterhub/ssl_cert/localhost.pem \
    -subj "/C=US/ST=MA/L=Boston/O=Organization/OU=OrganizationalUnit/CN=localhost" && \
    chmod 600 /srv/jupyterhub/ssl_cert/localhost.key && \
    chmod 644 /srv/jupyterhub/ssl_cert/localhost.pem

# Generate cookie secret and JUPYTERHUB_CRYPT_KEY
RUN mkdir -p /srv/jupyterhub && \
    openssl rand -hex 32 > /srv/jupyterhub/cookie_secret && \
    chmod 600 /srv/jupyterhub/cookie_secret && \
    echo "export JUPYTERHUB_CRYPT_KEY=$(openssl rand -hex 32)" >> /etc/profile.d/jupyterhub.sh && \
    chmod +x /etc/profile.d/jupyterhub.sh

# Copy JupyterHub configuration file
COPY jupyterhub_config.py /etc/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py

# Create a non-root user to run JupyterHub and add to docker group
RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash jupyterhub && \
    groupadd -g 999 docker && \
    usermod -aG docker jupyterhub

# Set up admin user with password
RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash admin && \
    echo "admin:adminpassword" | chpasswd

# Change ownership of directories and files
RUN chown -R jupyterhub:jupyterhub /etc/jupyterhub /srv/jupyterhub /var/log/jupyterhub /app && \
    chmod 755 /srv/jupyterhub && \
    chmod 644 /etc/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py

# Switch to non-root user
USER jupyterhub

# Expose port 8000
EXPOSE 8000

# Command to run JupyterLab with Poetry
CMD ["poetry", "run", "jupyter", "lab", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--no-browser", "--allow-root"]



#jupyterhub_config.py

import os
import sys
import pwd
import subprocess
from nativeauthenticator import NativeAuthenticator

c = get_config()

# JupyterHub settings
c.JupyterHub.ip = '0.0.0.0'
c.JupyterHub.port = 8000

# SSL configuration
ssl_key = '/srv/jupyterhub/ssl_cert/localhost.key'
ssl_cert = '/srv/jupyterhub/ssl_cert/localhost.pem'
if os.path.exists(ssl_key) and os.path.exists(ssl_cert):
    c.JupyterHub.ssl_key = ssl_key
    c.JupyterHub.ssl_cert = ssl_cert
else:
    print(f"SSL files not found. Key: {ssl_key}, Cert: {ssl_cert}")
    print("Contents of /srv/jupyterhub/ssl_cert:")
    print(os.listdir('/srv/jupyterhub/ssl_cert'))

# Authentication
c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = 'nativeauthenticator.NativeAuthenticator'
c.Authenticator.admin_users = {'admin'}
c.Authenticator.allowed_users = {'admin'}

# NativeAuthenticator specific configurations
c.NativeAuthenticator.open_signup = True
c.NativeAuthenticator.ask_email_on_signup = True
c.NativeAuthenticator.minimum_password_length = 8
c.NativeAuthenticator.check_common_password = True

# Spawner configuration
c.JupyterHub.spawner_class = 'dockerspawner.DockerSpawner'
c.DockerSpawner.image = 'elijun831/qiskit-on-docker:jupyterhub'
c.DockerSpawner.use_internal_ip = True
c.DockerSpawner.host_ip = '0.0.0.0'
c.DockerSpawner.volumes = {'/var/run/docker.sock': '/var/run/docker.sock'}
c.DockerSpawner.notebook_dir = '/home/jovyan/work'

# Pre-spawn hook
def pre_spawn_hook(spawner):
    username = spawner.user.name
    try:
        pwd.getpwnam(username)
    except KeyError:
        subprocess.check_call(['useradd', '-ms', '/bin/bash', username])
    
    # Set environment variables
    spawner.environment['NB_USER'] = username
    spawner.environment['CHOWN_HOME'] = 'yes'
    spawner.environment['CHOWN_EXTRA'] = '/home/jovyan/work'
    spawner.environment['CHOWN_HOME_OPTS'] = '-R'

c.Spawner.pre_spawn_hook = pre_spawn_hook

# Post-spawn hook to create admin user
def create_admin_user(spawner):
    if spawner.user.name == 'admin':
        auth = spawner.authenticator
        if not auth.check_user_exists('admin'):
            auth.add_user('admin', 'quantum')
            print("Admin user created")
        else:
            print("Admin user already exists")

c.Spawner.post_spawn_hook = create_admin_user

# Set default URL to JupyterLab
c.Spawner.default_url = '/lab'

# Database
c.JupyterHub.db_url = 'sqlite:////srv/jupyterhub/jupyterhub.sqlite'

# Logging
c.JupyterHub.log_level = 'INFO'

# DockerSpawner environment
c.DockerSpawner.environment = {
    'JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB': 'yes',
    'RESTARTABLE': 'yes'
}

# Set idle culler to remove inactive servers
c.JupyterHub.services = [
    {
        'name': 'idle-culler',
        'admin': True,
        'command': [sys.executable, '-m', 'jupyterhub_idle_culler', '--timeout=3600']
    }
]

# Cookie secret
c.JupyterHub.cookie_secret_file = '/srv/jupyterhub/cookie_secret'

# Startup message
print("JupyterHub Configuration:")
print("Admin username: admin")
print("Admin password: quantum")
print("New users can sign up at /hub/signup")
print("JupyterHub is ready to serve!")

# Debug: Print SSL directory contents
print("Contents of /srv/jupyterhub/ssl_cert:")
print(os.listdir('/srv/jupyterhub/ssl_cert'))



#pyproject.toml

[tool.poetry]
name = "qiskit-packages"
version = "1.0.0"
description = "Qiskit and quantum computing-related PyPI packages"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.9,<3.12"
matplotlib-inline = ">=0.1.0,<3.9.0"
jupyterlab = "*"
notebook = "*"
.
.
.
jupyterhub = "*"
dockerspawner = "*"
passlib = "*"
ipython = "*"
pycurl = "*"
tornado = "*"
etcd3 = "*"
bcrypt = "*"
jupyterhub-idle-culler = "*"
jupyterhub-nativeauthenticator = "*"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

Dockerfile: Sets up a Python 3.11 environment, installs necessary packages, and configures JupyterHub.
docker-compose.yml: Defines the JupyterHub service, volumes, and networking.
jupyterhub_config.py: Configures JupyterHub settings, authentication, and spawner options.
pyproject.toml: Lists Python dependencies for the project.
When I run docker compose up, JupyterHub starts, but I'm unable to log in with the admin credentials (username: admin, password: quantum) that are set in the configuration. The login page shows "Invalid username or password."
Additionally, the console output shows several warnings:
Config option 'init_handlers' not recognized by JupyterHub.
Config options 'create_system_users' and 'allow_signup' not recognized by NativeAuthenticator.
Warning about no allow config found, suggesting nobody can log in.
I've attempted to create an admin user in the configuration, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected.
GCP VM CLI
JupyterHub login page
Can someone help identify why the admin login isn't working and how to resolve these configuration warnings? Is there a problem with how I'm setting up the admin user or configuring the authenticator?
I tried setting up a JupyterHub instance using Docker with the following key configurations:
In the Dockerfile, I created an admin user:
RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash admin && \
    echo "admin:adminpassword" | chpasswd

In jupyterhub_config.py, I configured the admin user:
c.Authenticator.admin_users = {'admin'}
c.Authenticator.allowed_users = {'admin'}

I also added a post-spawn hook to create the admin user:
def create_admin_user(spawner):
    if spawner.user.name == 'admin':
        auth = spawner.authenticator
        if not auth.check_user_exists('admin'):
            auth.add_user('admin', 'quantum')
            print("Admin user created")
        else:
            print("Admin user already exists")

c.Spawner.post_spawn_hook = create_admin_user

I expected to be able to log in to JupyterHub using the username "admin" and password "quantum". However, when I try to log in, I get an "Invalid username or password" error.
Additionally, I expected the configuration to work without warnings, but I'm seeing several warnings about unrecognized config options and a message suggesting that nobody can log in to the Hub.
I was expecting a fully functional JupyterHub instance with working admin credentials and proper user authentication, but instead, I'm encountering login failures and configuration warnings.
